# Gallery mode: Allow room owner to see messages from those not authorised to speak

Tags: feature-request, chat

I've just been in a chat without the ability to speak, and I'm under the impression that not even the owner could see my messages. Given that SO in general doesn't have a private messaging system, it would be useful if owners and administrators could see chats from those not authorised to speak.

Comment: I think that's pretty much by design. Otherwise, the room owner might be swamped with the very messages that they're hoping to squelch. Seems sort of self defeating to make it otherwise, no?

Comment: @TimPost How many people know that the system swallows messages? In any case, I imagine it isn't beyond the whit of man to find a way to inform users of messages without showing the messages. Perhaps a number in a red circle corresponding to the unread messages?

Comment: BTW: you really shouldn't be able to type anything in a Gallery room if you're not on the write list. Where the textbox normally sits, you should see instead a short message and a "request access" button. If that's not the case, this is a bug (or you're not really in a gallery room).

Comment: @Shog9 Interesting. Certainly not what I saw today.

Answer (score 6):

> Given that SO in general doesn't have a private messaging system, it would be useful if owners and administrators could see chats from those not authorised to speak.

You mean... Like... *A private message system?*

The purpose - the *only* purpose - of creating a Gallery room is to be able to chat without getting interrupted by folks who aren't invited. Allowing them to interrupt *anyway* subverts this purpose. There's a button that lets you request access - if you do so, and your request is denied (or later revoked), that is the end of your dialogue with the room owner(s).

[image: What the room should look like when you don't have write access]

I'm always delighted by how many proposals for some form of private messaging involve an explicit desire to contact people who've already shown that they don't want to be contacted. It's a welcome reminder of why we *don't* have any generally-available PM feature.

Comment: Funnily enough, if the chat had such a button, I wouldn't be asking this question. As I commented above, I imagine it might be possible to make the message available to someone without forcing them to see it. If only such a design already existed.

Comment: As to "Allowing them to interrupt anyway subverts this purpose" - that's true but not relevant. A message shown only to administrators does not interrupt the conversation.

Comment: You said "owners and administrators" - room owners are the ones who could let you in; messaging administrators is already possible via email, but outside of very unusual circumstances, administrators aren't going to intervene. Regardless, if you're *not* seeing that message and button, there's something unusual going on - can you please post a bug report separately, detailing: which room you're in (with a link to it), which browser (and version) you're using, and which operating system (and version) you're running on. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please double-check that you're actually talking about a Gallery room and not a *Frozen* room, as the latter behave quite differently outside of one rather unusual scenario.

Comment: I have only the room owner's word to go on as to the type of the room - there was no indicator of its status.

Comment: There will be two indicators of a Gallery room: a gray padlock icon next to the name, and the text "Gallery: anyone may enter, but only approved users can talk" on the Access page. ([example](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/15/android?tab=access)).

Comment: As I say, not on this room. Certain other users were chatting away happily, and the creator mentioned placing the room in gallery mode.

Comment: Ahhh... Now I understand (maybe): if you were *already in the room* when it was placed in Gallery mode, the textbox may have remained.